# Python Scraping comprobar archivos duplicados antes de descargarlo o subirlo al servidor

Tags: python, scraping

Tengo un programa, el cual descarga archivos PDF de una web.
Por el momento, los guarda en local, la idea es que cuando esté finalizado, lo suba al servidor.

Mi pregunta es si es posible comprobar si el archivo que voy a descargar es idéntico al que ya tengo descargado o tiene algún cambio. De esa forma ahorrarme descargar y subir al servidor los que no han sufrido ningún cambio desde la última vez que se descargaron.

```
import requests
import filecmp


# Ruta de descarga de cada idioma
links={...}

# Funcion que compara y descarga los PDF
def descargar(rutaGuardado, rutaTemporal, identificador):
    for i in links.keys():
        if (links[i]!='X'):# Comprueba que existe PDF para este idioma
            r = requests.get(links[i], stream=True)
            # Crea la ruta donde se guardará, con el formato 'CG_empresa_idioma.pdf'
            ruta=rutaTemporal+'CG_block_'+identificador[i]+'.pdf'
            with open(ruta, 'wb') as Pypdf:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    if chunk:
                        Pypdf.write(chunk)
```

Ese es el código que tengo hasta el momento, a la funcion descargar la llamo desde otro archivo en el que le paso los parametros.

La razón de que haya rutaGuardado y rutaTemporal es porque al no saber si podía compararlo antes de descargarlo, pensaba guardarlo en una carpeta temporal y compararlo con el archivo de la ruta en red que sería el servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que la URL de la que te vas a descargar el PDF es la misma que aquella de la que ya te lo habías descargado, el protocolo HTTP te da un par de opciones para saber si lo que hay en esa URL ha cambiado o no, sin tener que descargarlo.

La primera vez que te descargues el fichero, mira si entre las cabeceras recibidas hay una llamada `ETags` o bien otra llamada `Last-modified`. En python lo mirarías por ejemplo así:

```
url = "https://i.imgur.com/GcK0UVr.jpg"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.headers.get("etag"))
print(r.headers.get("last-modified"))
```

Y saldría algo como lo siguiente (si esas cabeceras están presentes):

```
"755d43dd50a8ea9e3a28bcd1a8b29753"
Mon, 11 Nov 2019 07:45:23 GMT
```

La primera (etag) es una especie de hash del contenido del fichero. Si el fichero cambia, su etag cambiará también. La segunda es la fecha en la que ese fichero fue modificado. Cuando se modifique de nuevo se actualizará esa cabecera.

Has de guardar para cada URL que descargues esta información. Por ejemplo, puedes hacerlo en un diccionario en el que las claves sean las URLs y los valores otros diccionarios con los correspondientes etag y last-modified:

```
info = {} 
...
info[url] = { "etag": r.headers.get("etag"), 
              "last-modified": r.headers.get("last-modified") }
```

Se supone que una vez hayas descargado todas las URLs por primera vez, el diccionario `info` debes guardarlo en disco de alguna forma (por ejemplo usando pickle o convirtiéndolo a JSON). Y la próxima vez que ejecutes tu script, cargarás el diccionario `info` desde ese fichero, en lugar de inicializarlo con `{}`.

Tienes dos formas de sacar partido de esta información.

1. La próxima vez que vayas a pedir el fichero, usa `requests.head()` en lugar de `requests.get()`. Esto se bajará sólo las cabeceras. Puedes comparar los nuevos `etag` o `last-modified` con los que tenías guardados. Si han cambiado, vuelve a pedir el recurso pero esta vez con `get`, y actualiza `info`.
2. Puedes usar `requests.get()` directamente, pero añadir ciertas cabeceras en la petición, para que el servidor te devuelva el recurso solicitado *sólo si ha cambiado*. Las cabeceras a incluir serían:

   ```
   headers = {
     "If-modified-since": info[url]["last-modified"],
     "If-none-match": info[url]["etag"]
   }
   r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   ```

   Si el recurso no cambió, el servidor te devolverá un código de estado 304. Puedes comprobarlo desde python con un `if r.status_code == 304:` En ese caso no te envía el PDF, y eso que te ahorras. Si el recurso cambió, entonces el código de estado será 200 y en la respuesta viene el nuevo PDF y las nuevas cabeceras, que debes usar para actualizar `info`, para la próxima vez.

**NOTA** Todo esto depende de que el servidor "tenga a bien" enviarte las cabeceras `ETag` o `Last-modified`. Algunos no lo hacen. En ese caso no hay forma de saber, sin descargarlo, si el fichero cambió. Podrías hacer una estimación arriesgada pidiendo solo las cabeceras con `requests.head(url)` y buscando la cabecera `Content-Length`, y asumir que mientras la longitud en bytes del pdf sea la misma, es que no ha cambiado.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ! He comprobado todas las url, y en todas el servidor manda las cabeceras etag y last-modified, lo cual me facilitara mucho la tarea. Ha sido una explicacion perfecta